# File copy operation hangs on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu, files

I have an ntfs partition on my hard drive to store movies etc. Whenever i try to copy files (specifically large files i guess) into the ntfs partition copying operation hangs and copying speed is shown as "0". Same error occurs when copying to my usb harddisk. I cannot copy the movies i downloaded to my hard drives.

Is it a known bug or something? And of course, how can i fix that?

Comment: Does command-line copying work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy via terminal,

```
cp -Riv /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/movies /path/to/the/directory/you/want/to/paste/the/movies
```

Comment: Might want to include the verbose option when they're doing this, `-v`, so they can see where its hanging up.